Equation for the curve of a free falling particle in Kruskal diagram
I'm currently trying to help a friend who is taking a GR course (she is an experimentalist, and I'm rusty as hell, please be patient). We got stuck in an issue concerning Kruskal coordinates. We are loosely following Hartle's book Gravity: an introduction to Einstein's GR. On page 272, he shows a Kruskal diagram with the usual stuff, but he also draws the world line of 'free falling particle', or, of an observer who 'rides the surface of a collapsing ball of pressureless dust from large $r$ at $t = −\infty$ down to the singularity at $r=0$:

It's a kind of 'classic picture' in GR books, I remember seeing it in MWT years ago. Hartle states that this world line is given by the following equations:
$$ r(\tau) = (3/2)^{2/3} (2M)^{1/3} (\tau_* - \tau) \tag{12.7a}$$
$$ v(r) = 2M\left( \frac{r}{2M}-\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{r}{2M}\right)^{2/3}-2\left(\frac{r}{2M}\right)^{1/2} +2\log\left(1+ \left(\frac{r}{2M} \right)^{1/2} \right) \right) \tag{12.7b}$$
where $\tau_*$ is a integration constant and $v(r)$ is a nonsingular time coordinate for the 'collapsing ball'.
We got stuck trying to derive the equation of the curve of this 'free falling particle' drawn in the diagram. Here's our first try: since 12.7a and 12.7b are functions for radial and time coordinates of a free-falling particle, it seems intuitive to just put these functions in Kruskal coordinates:
$$X = \left(\frac{r}{2M}-1\right)^{1/2}e^{\frac{r}{4M}}\sinh\left(\frac{t}{4M} \right)\tag{*}$$
$$T = \left(\frac{r}{2M}-1\right)^{1/2}e^{\frac{r}{4M}}\cosh\left(\frac{t}{4M} \right) \tag{**},$$
but the outcome doesn't seems right. Our question is: since (*) and (**) are constructed based on radial null geodesics (which keeps the lightcones nice), should we 're-do' all the work from the ground with 12.7a and 12.7b to build some new $X'$ and $T'$ Kruskal coordinates in order to draw radial timelike geodesics in the diagram? Does this make any sense?

Welcome to Physics! Please note that homework-like questions and check-my-work questions are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer conceptual questions over those just asking for a specific computation. Notice that even if your question is not homework, it may still be homework-like.

@NíckolasAlves i would argue that this question has the potential to be very useful to future users.

I was wondering the same thing when I noticed that the worldline of a free falling particle in this Mthapages derivation of Kruskal  like coordinates https://mathpages.com/rr/s6-04/6-04.htm (diagram near the bottom) curves in the opposite direction to the free falling particle in the Wikipedia article.  Neither source gives the equation for the free falling particle. Ideally it would be nice to have a version of the coordinates where the free falling worldline is just a vertical line,, i.e the coordinates measured by a free falling observer that considers themselves to be stationary?

Wikipedia article on Kruskal Szekeres coordinates here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres_coordinates

What the Hurtle diagram fails to show is that when the observer starts falling, the black hole is still a dust cloud with radius greater than 2M so there is no event horizon at that time.

This is not intended to be a formal answer. \i just wanted to post the diagrams I referred to in the comment as I feel they may be useful to the discussion. This first one is from Mathpages;

This second diagram is from Wikipedia

Note that the freefalling worldlines curve in opposite directions in the two versions. I suspect the coordinates from Mathpages are his own version of the KS coordinates.
It is interesting to not that the worldline of the free falling observer in Hartle's diagram is simply a straight line very much like that of a free falling particle in the the related Rindler coordinates.

Indeed, that's confusing, I've seen too plenty of diagrams like those, some with the worldline bending to the right and other to the left close to the singularity, far from being a straight line as in MWT's and Hartle's. I've seen even people stating that it is a vertical straight line: https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.92.046008).  They don't justify it, it seems that they just 'borrow' a result from Rindler's diagram. I mean, it's a PhysRevD paper, hands up! I may have missed a point, I've read just some parts of it, bur I'm not sure about their move
